# RDS Proxy currently doesn’t support the option ssl_renegotiation_limit

Tags: amazon-rds, asp.net-core-3.1, npgsql, amazon-rds-proxy

I'm trying to connect to RDS PostgreSQL Proxy with enabled "Require Transport Layer Security" from .NET Core 3.1 Web API, using Npgsql 3.1.2

When I set SSLMode=Require in ConnectionString, I receive "RDS Proxy currently doesn’t support the option ssl_renegotiation_limit.". There was no problem setting up the SSL connection to the DB instance before introducing the proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newer versions of Npgsql no longer attempt to set `ssl_renegotiation_limit`. As Npgsql 3.1.2 was released in 2016, I'd highly recommend upgrading.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an answer just in case someone isn't able to quickly upgrade Npgsql quickly. Setting the `Server Compatability Mode` to `Redshift` will solve this issue

```
{...;sslmode=Require;Server Compatibility Mode=Redshift;...}
```

https://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html#compatibility

`ssl_renegotiation_limit` is also removed in Npgsql 4.1